# При изменении значения в QComboBox выполнить функцию. PySide2

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyside2, qcombobox

Есть два кортежа:

```
self.tables = ('table_1', 'table_2')
self.columns = (
    ('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3'),
    ('column_1', 'column_2')
)
```

Также есть два `QComboBox`, в первом хранятся значения из кортежа `self.tables`, во втором - значения из `self.columns`, которые соответствуют индексу выбранного элемента из первого `QComboBox`.

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе другого элемента в первом `QComboBox` выполнялась функция, заполняющая значениями второй `QComboBox`.

методы `.currentIndexChanged.connect()` и `.currentTextChanged.connect()` не работают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.currentTextChanged.connect()` очень даже работает, только `self.columns` вам надо сделать в виде словаря.

```
import sys 
#from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)

        self.tables = ('table_1', 'table_2')

        self.columns = {'table_1': ('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3'),
                        'table_2': ('column_1', 'column_2')}

        self.cbox_1  = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.cbox_1.move(10, 10)
        self.cbox_1.addItems(self.tables)
        self.cbox_1.currentTextChanged.connect(self.currentTextCbox_1)

        self.cbox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.cbox_2.move(100, 10)        
        self.cbox_2.addItems(self.columns['table_1'])

    def currentTextCbox_1(self, text):
        self.cbox_2.clear()
        self.cbox_2.addItems(self.columns[text])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

Правильнее будет использовать один словарь.

```
import sys 
#from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)

#        self.tables = ('table_1', 'table_2')
        self.columns = {'table_1': ('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3'),
                        'table_2': ('column_1', 'column_2')}

        self.cbox_1  = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.cbox_1.move(10, 10)
        self.cbox_1.addItems(self.columns.keys())
        self.cbox_1.currentTextChanged.connect(self.currentTextCbox_1)

        self.cbox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.cbox_2.move(100, 10)        
        self.cbox_2.addItems(self.columns['table_1'])

    def currentTextCbox_1(self, text):
        self.cbox_2.clear()
        self.cbox_2.addItems(self.columns[text])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: добрый вечер, у меня есть к вам вопрос по поводу Qt5, не могу кое в чем разобраться, не хочу выносить его на stack, тк информативности он не несет, а лишь мою глупость, есть ли способ с вами связаться?

Comment: @finally привет, по поводу Qt5 я слабый помощник :), а по поводу PyQt5, задавайте вопросы, поделюсь всем, что знаю и не скромничайте.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1041356/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyqt5-pyside2