# Не могу разобраться в подключении модулей и вызове окна PyQt5, PySide2

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, pyside2

Пишу обычный калькулятор, как на *windows*, *ios*, *android* и других платформах.

Создал макет в *Qt Designer*, перевел в **`.py`** используя

```
"C:\Python 3.7\Scripts\pyside2-uic.exe" "...\calc.ui" -o "...\calc.py"
```

После импортирую этот файл в другой, хочу вывести на экран само окно для начала.

Вот код самого окна:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.button_plus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_minus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_multiply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_divide = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_comma = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(262, 355)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(262, 355))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(262, 355))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft JhengHei UI")
        Form.setFont(font)
        Form.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
                           "    background-color: white; \n"
                           "    height: 40px;\n"
                           "    font-size:16px;\n"
                           "    font-weight:bold;}\n"
                           "\n"
                           "QPushButton:hover{\n"
                           "    background-color:silver;}\n"
                           "\n"
                           "QPushButton:pressed{\n"
                           "    background-color: silver;}")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 181, 221))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.button_1.setObjectName("button_1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button_5.setObjectName("button_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.button_2.setObjectName("button_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.button_6.setObjectName("button_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_6, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.button_7.setObjectName("button_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_7, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(-1)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.button_0.setFont(font)
        self.button_0.setObjectName("button_0")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_0, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.button_4.setObjectName("button_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_4, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button_9.setObjectName("button_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_9, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.button_8.setObjectName("button_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_8, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.button_comma.setObjectName("button_comma")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_comma, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.button_3.setObjectName("button_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.InfoLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.InfoLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 241, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.InfoLine.setFont(font)
        self.InfoLine.setObjectName("InfoLine")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 70, 51, 221))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.button_divide.setObjectName("button_divide")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_divide)
        self.button_multiply.setObjectName("button_multiply")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_multiply)
        self.button_minus.setObjectName("button_minus")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_minus)
        self.button_plus.setObjectName("button_plus")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_plus)
        self.button_equal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.button_equal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 241, 48))
        self.button_equal.setObjectName("button_equal")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, -1))
        self.button_1.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "1", None, -1))
        self.button_5.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "5", None, -1))
        self.button_2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "2", None, -1))
        self.button_6.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "6", None, -1))
        self.button_7.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "7", None, -1))
        self.button_0.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "0", None, -1))
        self.button_4.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "4", None, -1))
        self.button_9.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "9", None, -1))
        self.button_8.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "8", None, -1))
        self.button_comma.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", ",", None, -1))
        self.button_3.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "3", None, -1))
        self.button_divide.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "/", None, -1))
        self.button_multiply.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "X", None, -1))
        self.button_minus.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "-", None, -1))
        self.button_plus.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "+", None, -1))
        self.button_equal.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "=", None, -1))
```

---

Вот код, через который вызываю:

```py
import sys
from calc import *


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Сообщение об ошибке:

> TypeError: PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget isn't a direct base class of Main

Работаю по примеру, мало понятен порядок импорта модулей, все очень похожи.

Помогите вывести само окно, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> НИКОГДА не изменяйте модуль созданный в Qt Designerе !!!
>
> ## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

```
import sys
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from calc import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.button_plus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_minus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_multiply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_divide = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_comma = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    """
    
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(262, 355)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(262, 355))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(262, 355))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft JhengHei UI")
        Form.setFont(font)
        Form.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
                           "    background-color: white; \n"
                           "    height: 40px;\n"
                           "    font-size:16px;\n"
                           "    font-weight:bold;}\n"
                           "\n"
                           "QPushButton:hover{\n"
                           "    background-color:silver;}\n"
                           "\n"
                           "QPushButton:pressed{\n"
                           "    background-color: silver;}")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 181, 221))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_1.setObjectName("button_1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.button_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_5.setObjectName("button_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_2.setObjectName("button_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        
        self.button_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_6.setObjectName("button_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_6, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        
        self.button_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_7.setObjectName("button_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_7, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1) #(-1)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        
        self.button_0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_0.setFont(font)
        self.button_0.setObjectName("button_0")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_0, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        
        self.button_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_4.setObjectName("button_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_4, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_9.setObjectName("button_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_9, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.button_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_8.setObjectName("button_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_8, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.button_comma = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_comma.setObjectName("button_comma")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_comma, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_3.setObjectName("button_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.InfoLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.InfoLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 241, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.InfoLine.setFont(font)
        self.InfoLine.setObjectName("InfoLine")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 70, 51, 221))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.button_divide = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_divide.setObjectName("button_divide")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_divide)
        self.button_multiply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_multiply.setObjectName("button_multiply")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_multiply)
        self.button_minus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_minus.setObjectName("button_minus")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_minus)
        self.button_plus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_plus.setObjectName("button_plus")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_plus)
        self.button_equal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.button_equal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 241, 48))
        self.button_equal.setObjectName("button_equal")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, -1))
        self.button_1.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "1", None, -1))
        self.button_5.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "5", None, -1))
        self.button_2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "2", None, -1))
        self.button_6.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "6", None, -1))
        self.button_7.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "7", None, -1))
        self.button_0.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "0", None, -1))
        self.button_4.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "4", None, -1))
        self.button_9.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "9", None, -1))
        self.button_8.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "8", None, -1))
        self.button_comma.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", ",", None, -1))
        self.button_3.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "3", None, -1))
        self.button_divide.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "/", None, -1))
        self.button_multiply.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "X", None, -1))
        self.button_minus.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "-", None, -1))
        self.button_plus.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "+", None, -1))
        self.button_equal.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "=", None, -1))
        
# можно так:
#class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
#    def __init__(self, parent=None):
#        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
#        self.ui = Ui_Form()
#        self.ui.setupUi(self)
 
# но мне нравится так: 
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__ (parent)

        self.setupUi(self)    

        # тут ваша логика
        
        self.InfoLine.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.onButton_1)
        
    def onButton_1(self):
        self.InfoLine.setText(self.InfoLine.text() + self.button_1.text())
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from calc import Ui_Form
        
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__ (parent)

        self.setupUi(self)    

        # тут ваша логика
        
        self.InfoLine.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.onButton_1)
        
    def onButton_1(self):
        self.InfoLine.setText(self.InfoLine.text() + self.button_1.text())
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**calc.py**

```
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(262, 355)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(262, 355))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(262, 355))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft JhengHei UI")
        Form.setFont(font)
        Form.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
                           "    background-color: white; \n"
                           "    height: 40px;\n"
                           "    font-size:16px;\n"
                           "    font-weight:bold;}\n"
                           "\n"
                           "QPushButton:hover{\n"
                           "    background-color:silver;}\n"
                           "\n"
                           "QPushButton:pressed{\n"
                           "    background-color: silver;}")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 181, 221))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_1.setObjectName("button_1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.button_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_5.setObjectName("button_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_2.setObjectName("button_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        
        self.button_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_6.setObjectName("button_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_6, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        
        self.button_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_7.setObjectName("button_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_7, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1) #(-1)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        
        self.button_0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_0.setFont(font)
        self.button_0.setObjectName("button_0")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_0, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        
        self.button_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_4.setObjectName("button_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_4, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_9.setObjectName("button_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_9, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.button_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_8.setObjectName("button_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_8, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.button_comma = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_comma.setObjectName("button_comma")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_comma, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.button_3.setObjectName("button_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.InfoLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.InfoLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 241, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.InfoLine.setFont(font)
        self.InfoLine.setObjectName("InfoLine")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 70, 51, 221))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.button_divide = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_divide.setObjectName("button_divide")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_divide)
        self.button_multiply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_multiply.setObjectName("button_multiply")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_multiply)
        self.button_minus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_minus.setObjectName("button_minus")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_minus)
        self.button_plus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.button_plus.setObjectName("button_plus")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_plus)
        self.button_equal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.button_equal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 241, 48))
        self.button_equal.setObjectName("button_equal")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, -1))
        self.button_1.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "1", None, -1))
        self.button_5.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "5", None, -1))
        self.button_2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "2", None, -1))
        self.button_6.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "6", None, -1))
        self.button_7.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "7", None, -1))
        self.button_0.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "0", None, -1))
        self.button_4.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "4", None, -1))
        self.button_9.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "9", None, -1))
        self.button_8.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "8", None, -1))
        self.button_comma.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", ",", None, -1))
        self.button_3.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "3", None, -1))
        self.button_divide.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "/", None, -1))
        self.button_multiply.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "X", None, -1))
        self.button_minus.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "-", None, -1))
        self.button_plus.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "+", None, -1))
        self.button_equal.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "=", None, -1))
```

Comment: а если делать импорт в другой файл? тогда импортируем и берем класс Main?

Comment: @finally я добавил вариант с импортом

Comment: я так понял как то добавляет выравнивание справа для окошка?

Comment: @finally   `self.InfoLine.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)` почитайте https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#alignment-prop