# Как сделать элементарный интерфейс для калькулятора

Tags: python, pyqt5, интерфейс

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from calc2 import Ui_Dialog

# Апликация
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create form and init UI
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()

#Hooc logic

# Run main loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я поменял код но мне все ровно выдает ошибку но то лько другую

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calc2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from calc2 import Ui_Dialog
  File "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\calc\calc2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from calc2 import Ui_Dialog
ImportError: cannot import name 'Ui_Dialog' from partially initialized module 'calc2' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\calc\calc2.py)
```

Если нашли где-то ошибку то пишите номер строки и куда что надо писать заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: По логике `Ui_Dialog` должен быть классом, сгенерированным из ui файла, должен быть импортирован из внешнего модуля. Посмотрите пример в этой статье: [Конвертация файла .ui в файл .py при помощи pyuic5](https://python-scripts.com/pyqt5#convert-ui-to-py-pyuic5). Там `Ui_MainWindow` не взялся из ниоткуда, он был импортирован из модуля `mydesign`. Аналогично нужно сделать и вам.

Comment: я использую команду python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x kalkulator.ui -o kalkulator.py

Comment: Тогда добавьте в код `from kalkulator import Ui_Dialog`

Comment: Если я использую команду pyuic5 mydesign.ui -o mydesign.py то он мне выдает файл .py без if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Comment: insolor Я поменял код просмотрите все мои ошибки и скажите что я делаю не так а может у меня все неправильно! заранее спасибо вам!

Comment: PyQT Плохо подходит для новичков и калькуляторов.Используйте Tkinter там это проще сделано Пример кнопки и окна
```python
import tkinter
from tkinter import * new_window = Tk() # новое окно
new_button = Button(text="Привет") # кнопка с текстом Привет
new_button.place(x=0,y=0) # Поместить по X, 0, Y 0
new_window.mainloop() # отобразить окно
```
А дальше сможете сделать и сложные интерфейсы
Советую этот гайд,сам по нему учился.
[Урок PythonRU](https://pythonru.com/uroki/obuchenie-python-gui-uroki-po-tkinter)

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что вы в модуле calc2 импортируете тот же самый модуль calc2 - получается циклический импорт. Вместо этого вам нужно импортировать Ui_Dialog из сгенерированного файла (mydesign).

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1041356/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyqt5-pyside2/1041372#1041372 , внимательно прочитайте - `НИКОГДА не изменяйте модуль созданный в Qt Designerе !!!`